# ASP.Net MVC and PHP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My Question is straightforward.
I come across a random website that has been developed following the MVC pattern.

But how do I determine whether it is .Net MVC or PHP MVC? Is there a viable way to tell that from any indications?

Looking ahead to some insightful answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use this browser plugin (chrome + firefox), it can do it all for you :)

[Wappalyzer](http://wappalyzer.com/)

Comment: I have chrome and also have the Firebug installed to it for client script debugging. Now how do I use the combination of these two to determine the server technology?

Kindly tell me.

Comment: if you have successfully installed this add-on in your browser then you can see it's icon in the toolbar (in chrome at top right corner with a yellow box like icon).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `X-Powered-By` HTTP response header.  If it's not repressed then you should see either asp.net or php as the value.  There's also the `server` HTTP response header that is often set to Apache for php powered sites.

Comment: I viewed the page source and searched for the X-Powered-By header. It is absent. What now?